# Why the Pressure to Participate in United Way?

Tags: work-environment, united-states

Whenever I have worked for a company that participates in **United Way**, there has always been a lot of pressure to participate. I opt not to, because I am very active, financially and time-wise, with a charity I believe in. So it makes more sense for me to give directly. But there's always a series of high-pressure pitches and incentives for employees to contribute in some way to the fundraising campaign. Bake sales, employee meetings, direct conversation from the boss, promises of days off or casual jeans days, etc. *Why*?

Why is this high-pressure approach nearly always used? (I'm saying "nearly" because I don't know if it's always everywhere, but it's literally been always in my own experience.)

Comment: This is an impossible question to answer. There could be as many reasons as there are companies. Have you asked anyone at your company why? I personally suspect it's because they want to encourage social activism in a way that is perceived as apolitical and yet helpful. UW is respected so that achieves those goals.

Comment: What is United Way?

Comment: @MaskedMan "United Way" is an organization that collects contributions and distributes the money among a variety of charities. They mostly (?) work with big corporations to get them to have fund-raising drives among their employees, often arranging to have contributions made through deductions from the employees paycheck, so the employee commits to giving a certain amount over the course of the next year. See http://www.unitedway.org/

Comment: It should be mentioned in the description, people shouldn't have to search to understand the question.

Comment: @MaskedMan (shrug) I think most Americans know what United Way is. How much background should be included in a post and what asker can assume people should know is, I suppose, a question for Meta.

Comment: @Jay Who cares what Americans know? This is an international site, duh! As for Meta, [here you go](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/3216/3192).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Way_of_America and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Way_of_America#Scandals_and_criticism

Comment: I had a job where they did this and I always assumed the company got some sort of tax writeoff for it.

Comment: It's because the company can donate your donation from it's taxes.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this high-pressure approach nearly always used?

Because it makes those applying the "pressure" feel better/more successful when a higher percent of the company participates.

Companies typically assign an individual or group with the task of getting as many people as possible to participate in a company-sponsored charity (be it United Way or any other). It's some measure of "success" when all or nearly all employees sign up. Executives can talk about it to others, and some companies even put it on their website and point to it with pride.

And those designated with getting the signups want to please the company and thus do the best job they can.

Charities are very good at coming up with ways to gain high participation rates. When you describe as "high-pressure" is fairly common.

Choose to participate or not, as you like. Don't worry about "pressure".

Answer (score 0):

Why? Probably because the company sees giving to charity to be a good thing and wants to encourage it. Also, it makes the company look good if their employees give a lot. It's the sort of thing companies love to bring up when talking about themselves and how valuable they are to the community. "Our president and CEO gave himself a $1 million bonus" doesn't impress people too much. "We provide 5000 jobs and gave over half a million dollars through the United Way last year" sounds very nice.

Beyond that, as Mr Estep says in his comment, there could be any number of reasons, depending on the personalities of company executives, etc.

Comment: I had a coworker get a 'call' from the CEO after he questioned why the United Way contributions went to the city where corporate was located and not where our individual offices were (There were 4 large locations in a large metro area).  It comes down to as you said, the CEO gets to be seen publicly giving a very substantial check to the United Way.